# How is the relationship name of the DirectMessage with the DirectMessageMembers?

Tags: soql, direct-messaging

I want to make a query to get the DirectMessages with their members but I can't find the relationship name between these objects.
this is an example of what I want to do

```
SELECT 
id,
name,
subject, 
SystemModstamp,
(SELECT id,memberId FROM DirectMessageMember) 
FROM DirectMessage 
ORDER BY SystemModstamp desc
```

---

When I inspect the describe, it doesn't have the `relationshipName` field. [image]

Comment: If `relationshipName` is not defined, then that means this type of query join is not supported for this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com), you should be able to see the child relationships and the correct API name to use in a sub-query:

[image]